# Issue with Angular2 binding not updating on model change

Tags: angular, ionic2, ibeacon

On my related html angular 2 page the binding {{beacon1}} is used and correctly changes when doing it manually through other methods. However any changes to the model variables won't update binding when placed inside of a subscribe method. I believe this may have something to do with scope. The model itself changes after logging the value of this.beacon1 which shows a change but the rendered html doesn't change.

```
delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.beacon1 = data.toString(),
    error => console.error()
  );
```

For example above, on console logging this.beacon1 is updating to new values although isn't shown in rendered html. If this.beacon1 = "test" is used in a constructor it does however update.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Where do you console.log? What does the html look like?

Comment: Please provide more information about `delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion()`. What causes it to emit values?